# Menu not aligned with HStack

Tags: swiftui

I have this code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
  var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
      VStack {
        HStack {
          Text("MY APP")
          Spacer()
          
          Menu {
            
            Button(action: {
              withAnimation{
              }
            }, label: {
                Label("Sort",
                      systemImage: "checkmark")
            })
          } label: {
            Image(systemName: "ellipsis.circle")
            //          .foregroundColor(Color("orangeBar"))
          }
          
        }
        Spacer()
        NavigationLink {
          Text("Hello")
        } label: {
          Text("Click me")
        }
      }
      .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
      
      .ignoresSafeArea()
      .padding([.leading, .trailing], 30)

      .frame(height:.infinity)
      .navigationViewStyle(.stack)
      .navigationTitle("")

    }
  }
}
```

this is the result:

[image]

Notice how the ellipsis menu is not vertically aligned with the text `MY APP`.

Any way to make it align?

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you are ignoring the safe area, so the text (which touches the boundary to the safe area) is moving up into the safe area. The menu is not moving, maybe because it has some native margin around it which prevents it from touching the boundary to the safe area, or because it has some native placement logic that prevents it from going into the safe area.

Here are two ways to fix:

1. Comment out `.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)` and `.ignoresSafeArea()`. Then they align fine:

[image: AlignedNormal]

2. If you really want the title and the menu to be in the safe area then you can bring them into alignment by applying the menu as an overlay to the `HStack`:

```swift
HStack {
    Text("MY APP")
    Spacer()
}
.overlay(alignment: .bottomTrailing) {
    Menu {
        Button(action: {
            withAnimation{
            }
        }, label: {
            Label("Sort",
                  systemImage: "checkmark")
        })
    } label: {
        Image(systemName: "ellipsis.circle")
        //          .foregroundColor(Color("orangeBar"))
    }
}
```

[image: AlignedSafeArea]

BTW, it should probably be `maxHeight: .infinity`, not `height: .infinity`, because the latter is invalid. But you don't need this, because the `Spacer` inside the `VStack` ensures that the full height is used anyway. Also, `.edgesIgnoringSafeArea` is deprecated and not needed if you are using `ignoresSafeArea` already.

Comment: Sorry, but I am unable to replicate your results on my code. I will try discover why it is not working for me and return to this question.